# (Sonarqube) (Custom Plugin) (get SonarQube Session)

Tags: sonarqube5.1

Dear SonarQube developers,

I'd like to get the SonarQube *session* in "Initializer" phase, and put some object variables in the session in order to recover them when analyzing my custom rules.
So that I don't calculate these objects many times in the same analysis session.

Is it possible?
How can I do it?

Thanks a lot for you advice.

Wognin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using Java System Properties in the ProjectBuilder phase, this way :

```
ParametresProjet paramProj = parseFichierPom(projDef.getKeyWithBranch());

    if (paramProj != null) {
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        // sauvegarde des objets dans la session
        properties.put(PROPRIETES_DU_POM, paramProj );

        Boolean isException = ProjetControleur.isProjetEnException(paramProj.getGroupId(), paramProj.getArtifactId());

        properties.put(PROJET_EN_EXCEPTION, isException);
        System.setProperties(properties);
    }
```

And further I could recover these properties during the Java analyse, this way :

```
private static Boolean isException;

/** static initializer */
static {
    isException = (Boolean) System.getProperties().get(PROJET_EN_EXCEPTION);
}
```

That solved my problem but I don't know if it's a good approach to put and recover object in SonarQube's session.
What do you think about it ?

WOGNIN